# Padding output with newlines

Tags: command-line, output, text-formatting

I'd like to make fixed height output from any command using piping:

```
some_command | magic_command -40
```

If, for example, some_command prints 3 lines, magic_command should add 37 newlines,

or if some_command prints 50 lines, magic_command should cut extra lines (like head -40)

Comment: This is almost painfully straightforward. What have you tried and what problems are you facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
{ command; while :; do echo; done; } | head -n 40
```

On GNU system:

```
{ command; yes ""; } | head -n 40
```

Comment: Works great. Could you explain how does it work?

Comment: @login: `{ cmd1; cmd2; }` run two command as group, write their output to pipe. When `head` get 40 lines, it terminated, `{ cmd1; cmd2; }` continue writing to closed pipe, they received `SIGPIPE`, and quit.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk -v c=40 'NR>c{exit} 1; END{for(i=NR+1;i<=c;i++)print""}'
```

#### How it works

- `-v c=40`

  This defines the number of lines that we want.
- `NR>c{exit}`

  If we have printed more than `c` lines, then exit.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print the line.
- `END{for (i=NR+1; i<=c; i++) print ""}`

  If we have reached the end of the input, then keep printing blank lines until we read a total of `c` lines of output.

#### Examples

Just for illustration, we shorten the desired output to five lines:

```
$ seq 2 | awk -v c=5 'NR>c{exit} 1; END{for(i=NR+1;i<=c;i++)print""}'
1
2



$ seq 10 | awk -v c=5 'NR>c{exit} 1; END{for(i=NR+1;i<=c;i++)print""}'
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: To simplify `i=NR;i<c;i++`

Answer (score 1):

The *magic_command* can be followed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#USAGE: Pass output of any command via ./magic.sh LINE_NUMBER

i=$1
while ((i--)) ; do
    read && echo $REPLY || echo
done
```

Examples:

```
seq 4 | ./magic.sh 3
1
2
3
seq 4 | ./magic.sh 6
1
2
3
4
-  
-
```

- *«-» mark empty line(s)*